# Update stored procedure using C#?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have 10 database servers and most procedures are the same.
So I plan to make procedure distribute program.

For convenient application, I want to use "the procedure modify code made by tool" itself.
For example, when I click modify button of the procedure on SSMS the code is like below.

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[HongTestProcedure]    Script Date: 2020-08-28 오전 11:09:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      hong
-- Create date: 2020-03-07
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HongTestProcedure]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM table
END
```

And then, if I want to modify the parameter of the procedure.
Maybe the code is like below:

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[HongTestProcedure]    Script Date: 2020-08-28 오전 11:09:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      hong
-- Create date: 2020-03-07
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HongTestProcedure]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID varchar(10)
    @ID2 varchar(10) -- it is added.
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM table
END
```

I consider that program has a textbox and button.
and I want to insert all above code.
maybe it looks like it:

[image: prototype]

So, I try the code like below:

```
public bool UpdateProcedure(string dbip, string query)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("server = " + dbip + dbInfo);
    sqlConn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return true;
}
```

If it run successfully, I will run query on 10 database servers.
But it return error message. even it can be run in SSMS.

- incorrect syntax near 'GO'
- CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE must be the first statement in a query batch

Can I solve it?

Comment: Why roll your own? Why not use an well established, battle-tested, proven solution like [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [RoundhousE](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) instead of re-inventing the wheel yet again?

Comment: "GO" is not a SQL command, it is a delimiter specific to SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since you can construct it as an Dynamic SQL in C# and Open an SQL Connection and pass the Dynamic SQL to `EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL`. This will create the required SP in the required Database.

Comment: Wow. if it is possible, it help me a lot. however, i try in c#. it doesn't work. So, first i try to run in SSMS. (like EXEC sp_executesql N'@AboveQuery'). but it has two issue. first, it also return same error message above. it also need to remove 'GO'. second it need to modify query, if there is Quotes, double Quotes is required. Am I doing what you intended?

Comment: @H.YK, you can execute scripts with `GO ` batch separators using the SMO library `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery` method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery?view=sql-smo-160.